# Syntax error when trying to run an IF EXISTS query

Tags: mysql, sql, sequelpro

I am trying to run the below query (in Sequel Pro), but I am getting the following syntax error:

```
 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to 
  your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF 
  (EXISTS(SELECT username FROM USER WHERE username = "TestObserver")) 
  {SELECT *' at line 1'
```

Code:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT username FROM USER WHERE username = "TestObserver") 
SELECT * FROM USER WHERE username = "TestObserver"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use an `if` block outside of a function. Instead just run the subsequent SQL statement:

```
SELECT * FROM `USER` WHERE username = "TestObserver"
```

If there is no username with `testobserver` value it will already return nothing all by itself.

Comment: Thanks for your response